# Android - Deeplinking - Handle two same urls with different query string

Tags: android, url, android-manifest, deep-linking

I have one issue related to deep linking.
I have two urls starting with something like “https://www.myweb.com/Logon” with different query string parameters. Now what happens is both the urls opens the app, what I want is to make only one url to open my app while to restrict the other one in doing so.

Here is my manifest code.

`<data
     android:host="www.myweb.com"
     android:pathPrefix="/Logon"
     android:scheme="https" />`

My urls

1.https://www.myweb.com/Logon?Action=View&Id=13456789&Sid=123456789
2.https://www.myweb.com/Logon?resume=/abc/AqAbA/resumeAqAbA

When I open both urls in Mobile browser both the urls shows the pop up to whether to continue this url in application or browser. I want only 1st url to show popup.

**Note: Second url must not open in application.It must continue with browser itself.**

does pathPattern property gonna help in this case ?

Any suggestions/help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your launcher Activity, you can get the uri like this

```
    Intent  intent = getIntent();
    Uri uri;
    if (intent != null) {
        uri = intent.getData();
    }
    String url = uri.toString();
    if (url.contains("Action")) {
       // do something
    }else if(url.contains("resume")){
       // do something else
    }
```

you can also find the required parameter from the url with some string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what i want is to restrict other (2nd) url to even open the application. I want only 1st url to show popup to open that url in my application.

Comment: @BhargavVasani : frankly speaking you can not. Only thing you can do it that handle that through intent and finish your activity.